# Object orientated mysql num_rows query in one line

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, object-oriented-database

Essentially, what I want to do is remove the extra $result line and have it all in one IF statement. Is this possible in PHP using object-orientated queries?

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id ='".$user."'");
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    // Continue...
}else{
    // Does not exist, create...
}
```

Comment: simply use if($result) {...} If there is no result, the return is a null variable, which will be a false if used in if()

Answer (score 2):

First, let me blame your intention.
"To do something in one line" (implying "using some syntax tricks") **is not the way to go.**

OOP can shorten your code, but not the way you are asking. To shorten this code using OOP means to create a class with some method to call:

```
if ($user->exists($user)) {
    // Continue...
}else{
    // Does not exist, create...
}
```

This is how OOP works.

While inside of exists() method you have to use usual multiline code. However, you can shorten it too, using a [**database class**](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) in turn:

```
function exists($id)
{
    return (bool)$this->db-getOne("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?i", $id);
}
```

Also, let me note that you are not using **prepared statements**, which renders mysqli totally **useless**.